# Am I correct to not use a <nav> tag for my secondary navigation?

Tags: html, wordpress, navigation

I'm building up a Wordpress HTML5 template, and I'm wondering if my structure for the header navigation is correct.

[image]

So as you can see on the screenshot, I have one "main" menu (musique/arts/design...), and another "secondary" menu on the upper right (a propos/publicité...). My concern is about that last one. This is the HTML I've chosen:

```
<div class="header-nav grid_6">
  <ul id="menu-top-menu" class="clearfix">
    <li id="menu-item-217" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom first-menu-item menu-item-217"> <a href="http://#">A propos</a> </li>
    <li id="menu-item-218" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-218"> <a href="http://#">Publicité</a> </li>
    <li id="menu-item-219" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-219"> <a href="http://#">Partenaires</a> </li>
    <li id="menu-item-220" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom last-menu-item menu-item-220"> <a href="http://#">Contact</a> </li>
 </ul> 
</div>
```

As you can see it's really basic. I've decided to use just a `<ul>` element and not wrapping it into a `<nav>`, because [in the specs, it says that  must be some kind of major navigation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/spec.html#the-nav-element), and in my case I'm not sure that it's the case, as those links aren't really relevant to the main content that will be found on the site.

Could anyone tell me if I'm wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using HTML5 you should be using the `nav` tag

Comment: also `header` and `footer`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178761/html5-nav-tag-correct-usage

Comment: @KilianStinson I wouldn't call that a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got at least one important link in this menu : `contact`. Therefore I would have use this kind of pattern, with another `nav` tag :

```
<header class="container">

    <div class="grid_6">
        <h1>KORE</h1>
        <p id="baseline">Wordpress HTML 5 responsive boilerplate based on 996css grid</p>
    </div>
    <nav class="grid_6">
        <a href="">À propos</a>
        <a href="">Publicité</a>
        <a href="">Partenaires</a>
        <a href="">Contact</a>
    </nav>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <nav class="grid_12">
        <a href="">Musique</a>
        <a href="">Art</a>
        <a href="">Design</a>
        <a href="">Lifestyle</a>
        <a href="">Podcasts</a>
        <a href="">Sortir</a>
    </nav>

</header>
```

Comment: Does one important link qualify a list of links for a `nav` tag though? The HTML5 spec mentions a group of footer links including Terms of Service as an example of a group that wouldn't require a `<nav>` tag.  Terms of Service can have legal implications, so you'd think it'd be pretty important.

Comment: Thanks @zessx, didn't think of the contact link as important. Makes sense now to use the <nav> element. And by the way, I was aware about using <header> <nav> etc, I just pasted this heading navigation code, the rest is fine!

Comment: But then @PaulD.Waite makes is trouble eheh

Comment: For most of customers, a `Terms of Service` link has less interest than a `Contact` link, I guess. We don't need a `Terms of Service` link to be 'caught' by search engines.

Comment: @zessx: but then maybe for this site "Contact" isn't very important either. And is `<nav>` intended for search engines? I thought the main use case was screen readers, to make it easier for a user to immediately switch to the main site navigation. (I can't remember why I thought this though, so I could well be entirely wrong.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite This is the orginal purpose of `<nav>`, but search engines robots will use it for their own needs. And I agree, if `Contact` isn't that important, there's no need to use `nav`.

Comment: @zessx: cool cool. Are there any current real-world examples of search engines using `<nav>`?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I didn't read anything official about it, but navigation is a very important factor in SEO, so don't care about `<nav>` tags would be stupid, imo.

Comment: @zessex: “navigation is a very important factor in SEO” — is it? How so?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32545/discussion-between-zessx-and-paul-d-waite)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `nav` tag for the navigation.

According to the specification

> The nav element represents a section of a document that links to other documents or to parts within the document itself; that is, a section of navigation links.

So you can use the `nav` for all kinds of menus/navigational links.
Also it is a good idea to use the `header` and `footer` tags.

Once you use the `nav` and `header` tags you can reduce the number of classes by using these tags directly in your CSS like below.

```
header {
    /*style header*/
}
nav {
    /*style navigation*/
}
```

Comment: But then, also according to the specification: "Not all groups of links on a page need to be in a `nav` element — the element is primarily intended for sections that consist of major navigation blocks. In particular, it is common for footers to have a short list of links to various pages of a site, such as the terms of service, the home page, and a copyright page. The footer element alone is sufficient for such cases; while a `nav` element can be used in such cases, it is usually unnecessary."